# Missing list of tables in Sqlite Manager Firefox Add-on

Tags: sqlite, firefox-addon, sqlitemanager

With the Sqlite Manager Add-on in Firefox.

On the left, there has always been a list of the tables that are in the currently opened database.

I must have closed something, because it's not there anymore... and I can't figure out how to reopen it... or, at least reset everything.

Comment: Please be more specific as to how this specifically relates to programming.  As it is, this question appears to be more about how to use the Firefox add-on [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) to manage a database.  As such, it may be more appropriate to another StackExchange site (e.g. [superuser](http://superuser.com/), or [dba.se]).

Answer (score 0):

You have to select a table from the top right and then click on "Go". As seen in this screenshot:

[image]